# case when with subquery syntax

Tags: sql, case

I need to retrieve values according to the input parameter  
Exemple :
 param = A , result = AB 
          param = B , result = BA , BB

I know i need to use case when statements but i have some troubles with implementing them 
Any help would be appreciated

Parameter = 'A'

```
select distinct(statut.STATUT_NAME)as statutList ,
case 'A'
when 'A' then (select distinct(STATUT_NAME) as statutAllowed  from STATUT  where STATUT_NAME = 'AB')
when 'B' then (select distinct(STATUT_NAME) as statutAllowed from STATUT where STATUT_NAME = 'BA' and STATUT_NAME = 'BB')
end
from STATUT statut;
// request should returns AB
```

Parameter = 'B'

```
select distinct(statut.STATUT_NAME)as statutList ,
case 'B'
when 'A' then (select distinct(STATUT_NAME) as statutAllowed  from STATUT where STATUT_NAME = 'AB')
when 'B' then (select distinct(STATUT_NAME) as statutAllowed from STATUT where STATUT_NAME = 'BA' and STATUT_NAME = 'BB')
end
from STATUT statut;
// request should returns BA , BB
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare the variable and use it in your case, instead of hard-coding the value in the case.

```
declare @param char(1)

select distinct(statut.STATUT_NAME)as statutList,
case @param 
when 'A' then (select distinct(STATUT_NAME) as statutAllowed  from STATUT where STATUT_NAME = 'AB')
when 'B' then (select distinct(STATUT_NAME) as statutAllowed from STATUT where STATUT_NAME = 'BA' and STATUT_NAME = 'BB')
end
from STATUT statut;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `Case Statement` like this. Mention the `param` column as **input expression** in Case statement

```
SELECT DISTINCT( statut.STATUT_NAME )AS statutList,
               CASE param
                 WHEN 'A' THEN (SELECT DISTINCT( STATUT_NAME ) AS statutAllowed
                                FROM   STATUT
                                WHERE  STATUT_NAME = 'AB')
                 WHEN 'B' THEN (SELECT DISTINCT( STATUT_NAME ) AS statutAllowed
                                FROM   STATUT
                                WHERE  STATUT_NAME = 'BA'
                                       AND STATUT_NAME = 'BB')
               END
FROM   STATUT statut;
```

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you want this:

```
select distinct(s.STATUT_NAME) as statutList
from STATUT s
where (@param = 'A' and s.statut_name = 'AB') or
      (@paraem = 'B' and s.statut_name in ('BA', 'BB'));
```

Some observations:

- The subqueries in your version have no impact whatsoever, because the outer `select` is on a different field.
- Your version doesn't mention the parameter name, which I've just called `@param`.
- The `'B'` clause in your version will always return 0, because the `where` clause has an `AND` in it, and both conditions cannot be true at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for your advices , i will take them in account . I need to use 'in' indeed instead 'and'